# Fetching value into form from MySql database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to fetch value from MySql database. I have a form where i want to fetch emailid from the MySql db. Please Help

```
<tr><td><b>Email :</td><td><input type="text" name="txtemail" readonly value="<?php
$name=$_SESSION['usr_name'];
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name="test"; // Database name 

$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("cannot connect"); 

mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT emailid FROM tabledetails WHERE    
username='$name'");

echo $result;
mysqli_close($conn);
?>">
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: The form is getting displayed but field is blank

Comment: can u clearly explain what is u r requirement?

Comment: `mysqli_query` returns a `mysqli_result` object not a string - your `echo` isn't going to work - there's probably a "cannot convert object to string" type error in your log file (since you've not got errors displayed I assume).

Comment: My requirement is i have a from which allows user to book room for meetings. I want the details of the user i.e Email Id to be fetched from the db & send email when user clicks submit.In email i want to give the details of date & time for booking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working perfectly in my local system:

try this code as per your requirement:

```
<?php
$name=$_SESSION['usr_name']
$servername="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$dbname="test"; // Database name 
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
else{
echo "Connected successfully";
}

$res  = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT emailid FROM tabledetails WHERE username='$name'");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
{
$rows = $row['email'];
 print_r $rows;
 echo $rows;   
}
?>
<tr><td><b>Email :</td><td><input type="text" name="txtemail" readonly value="<?php echo $rows ?>"/>
```

**Output:-**

```
Connected successfully
Email :User
```

Comment: Thanks It's Working. But 1 issue i got is that this is a form for booking room & the email id is getting printed on top of form as well

Comment: Your form and php code are in same file or diffrent file?

Comment: Same. Infact This is a big file where i am giving this form to book a room.

Comment: So what is the problem,you just give the email value as a <?php echo $rows ?> in Email field.

Comment: Sorted! Actually i didn't comment the echo part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove this line.

```
mysqli_select_db($conn,$db_name);
```

and add 4th parameter to mysqli_connect

```
$conn=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password, $db_name) or die("cannot connect");
```

for more detail
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: 1: makes no (practical) difference, 2: w3schools is not a definitive source.

Comment: @CD001 1. I agree. 2. This is not official. W3schools is still 80% legit.

Comment: @CD001 : thanks for info. I think this is the difference between in mysql and mysqli

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["Email"];
    }
```